# Javascript variable to dynamically change based on value of DOM that matches object pairs

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following obj;

```js
var set = [
    {"desc":"Standard","code":"C1S"},
    {"desc":"Superior","code":"B2T"},
    {"desc":"Standard","code":"A1K"}
];
```

Then I have a DOM that outputs the "desc" value of the selected object in the page, for instance:

```js
document.querySelector('.ResRoom .infoIcoAfter').innerHTML;
```

The above document.querySelector returns either "Standard", "Superior", or "Deluxe".

I want to create a variable in JS that returns the counterpart "code" vvalue of the selection made. For example, if the above document.querySelector returns "Standard", I need this new variable to have value = "C1S".

Can someone help?
Thanks much in advance.
A.

Comment: Please put relevant code for your question. Could you put your whole js 
code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is using the function `find`.

Assuming `target = document.querySelector('.ResRoom .infoIcoAfter').innerHTML;`

**Aside note:** Use `textContent` instead to avoid problems with styles, nested elements, Etc.

```js
let target = 'Standard',
    set = [{"desc":"Standard","code":"C1S"},{"desc":"Superior","code":"B2T"},{"desc":"Standard","code":"A1K"}],
    found = set.find(({desc}) => desc === target),
    code = found ? found.code : '';

console.log(code);
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for, thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one match for Standard in your example, so the below function will return an array.

```js
var set = [{"desc":"Standard","code":"C1S"},{"desc":"Superior","code":"B2T"},{"desc":"Standard","code":"A1K"}];

function getCodesForType(name, set){
  return set.filter(function(item){ return item.desc == name; }).map(function(item){ return item.code; });
}

console.log(getCodesForType("Standard", set));
```